# Setting variables inside a SELECT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm in the process of rewriting a `mySQL 5.7` query to `Snowflake`. I would like to keep as much of the `mySQL` query as close as possible when converting to `Snowflake`.

**PROBLEM**: The issue that I'm facing is that I have some user defined variables that change dynamically based on the previous value in a given column and I'm unable to replicate that functionality. I've been able to `set` variables but when I attempt to change their value as described I'm presented with a series of error.

**MySQL Query**:

```
SELECT
    temp.id,
    temp.profile_id,
    temp.citations,
    temp.DataValue,
    @rank := CASE
        WHEN @prevId = temp.profile_id AND @prevDataValue = temp.DataValue THEN @rank+1
        ELSE 1
    END as DataValueRank,
    @prevId := temp.profile_id AS prevId,
    @prevDataValue := temp.DataValue AS prevDataValue
FROM
    l.temp AS temp,
    (SELECT @prevId := 0, @prevDataValue := 0, @rank := 0) AS X
ORDER BY
    profile_id DESC,
    DataValue ASC,
    citations DESC
```

in the above query we have that @prevId will be the value of the previous value found in the `profile_id` column,  similarly for `@prevDataValue` and `DataValue`.

The table that gets created looks like the following:

```
id          profile_id     citations   DataValue           DataValueRank   prevId       prevDataValue
...
24508771    1003077033      1           E04.936.580.225     49             1003077033   E04.936.580.225
24160975    1003077033      1           E04.987             50             1003077033   E04.987
24160975    1003077033      1           E04.987.775         51             1003077033   E04.987.775
28079605    1003077025      9           C10                  1             1003077025   C10
28079605    1003077025      9           C10.597              2             1003077025   C10.597
...
```

Where `l.temp` is the same as above with the last three columns:

```
id          profile_id     citations    DataValue           
...
24508771    1003077033      1           E04.936.580.225     
24160975    1003077033      1           E04.987             
24160975    1003077033      1           E04.987.775         
28079605    1003077025      9           C10
28079605    1003077025      9           C10.597
...
```

**ATTEMPT**

**Snowflake Query**

```
SET (prevId, prevDataValue, rank) = (0, 0, 0); -- AS X
```

I'm thinking that this acts as my variable initializer similar to

```
SELECT @prevId := 0, @prevDataValue := 0, @rank := 0) AS X

SELECT
    temp.id,
    temp.profile_id,
    temp.citations,
    temp.DataValue,
--    $rank = CASE
--        WHEN $prevId = temp.profile_id AND $prevDataValue = temp.DataValue THEN $rank+1
--        ELSE 1
--    END as DataValueRank, -- THIS WON'T CHANGE VALUE DEPENDING ON THE CASE
--    $prevId = temp.profile_id, -- THIS WON'T CHANGE VALUE
--    $prevDataValue = temp.DataValue -- THIS WON'T CHANGE VALUE
    FROM
        DATAWAREHOUSE.MY_DATA AS temp,
    ORDER BY
        profile_id DESC,
        DataValue ASC,
        citations DESC
;
```

If anybody knows how the variables can change value within the `SELECT` statement that would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change values of SQL variables within the SELECT statement. Only possible option is to use SET command to assign/change value of an SQL variable in Snowflake:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html

I understand that MySQL's variables is very useful, but Snowflake does not support same functionality.